# BMS design question

Tags: short-circuit, bms

I recently came across this popular BMS design and I am trying to understand the circuit design
[image]

[image]

There are some great technical discussions around it, like on [robojax](https://robojax.com/complete-guide-using-3s-40a-lithium-bms-battery-charger) or [this non-English forum](http://www.78294.ru/forum/23-232-1).

Most parts are pretty straight forward. Below is my understanding of the the [original schematics](http://www.78294.ru/forum/23-232-1):

1. Balancing module: discharging through 100R RES when cell reaches certain voltage.
2. Battery cell
3. Protection module: pull down pin 1 when cell is over-voltage, pin 3 when under-voltage. This, through various transistors, would then control the MOSFETs
4. MOSFETs for over-voltage / over-charge protection
5. MOSFETs for under-voltage / over-discharge protection

My main question is **what is the function of (6)**?

[This author](http://www.78294.ru/forum/23-232-1) mentioned that, during short-circuit event, (6) **turns off MOSFET until after the load is removed**. After load removal, the circuit would work normally again. [robojax](https://robojax.com/complete-guide-using-3s-40a-lithium-bms-battery-charger) also did a great video experiment showing this function. However, my [simulation on circuit lab](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/3mnyemd4rtar/bms-discharge-public/) shows that  it would always pull down the MOSFETs gate and never allow the battery to discharge.

Could someone please explain?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> My main question is what is the function of (6)?

Subcircuit 6 prevents voltage across the main FET module-4 from rising to more than 1.2V. This voltage is dropped across the combined Rdsons of the FETs in the module. It is possible that base and wiring capacitance at the base of Q8 cause Q8 to delay turn on briefly and then to remain on when FET current drops but, if so, this is not a formal part of circuit function.

---

Q8 is usually held off by the 1M across Q8_be.
When the voltage across FET_Module_4_DS exceeds 1.2V then the 2 x 1M resistors provide 0.6V to Q8, turning it on and clamping FET_module_4 gate to source.
This does not turn the FET hard off as the reduced FET gate drive reduces FET_DS drop and starts to turn off the clamping circuit - so the module remains on with a drop of about 1.2 V across it. There MAY be some hysteresis that I have missed, but if so I have missed it :-) .

This would be a very unhealthy state for the FET module to remain in for any period as dissipation is I_load^2 x 1.2 V.
Without following the whole operation I assume the path through Q7 may have a secondary controlling effect. Maybe not.

It is not obvious why the arrangement should always pull down the MOSFET gate as Q8 can only be turned on when FET Vds is >= 1.2v.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is confusingly drawn but it's a variation on this standard current limit topology:
[Voltage and Current Limiting Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35328/voltage-and-current-limiting-circuit)

The BJT is used like a comparator to sense if the voltage across the shunt exceeds its Vbe threshold.  If so it pulls down the gate of the pass fet thus limiting current.

A subtle difference here is that instead of sensing voltage directly at the shunt it senses it from the mosfet drain.  This forms a clever latch.  Once the BJT is triggered (by excessive current making ~1.2V at the drain) it turns the pass fet off.  This makes drain voltage rise even more which turns the BJT on harder.  The circuit is now latched off until the load is removed and voltage at the drain can fall back down.

This latching is desirable behavior for a BMS and, as importantly, ensures the circuit doesn't linger in the linear region and blow up the fet.

Here is a sim redrawing one half of the circuit:
[image]